# Svg List Style animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a couple of list styles that I would like to animate when the svg's LI is hovered over. The issue I am getting is that the first LI triggers all list Items to animate at the same time. I have tried using just css, and I have also tried using jquery, but I just can figure it out for the life of me. Thanks! You can check my code [here](https://codepen.io/SSelke/pen/EQwVWL)

```
<ul class="blogs-ul">
                <li class="one">
                    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                         viewBox="0 0 61.7 61.4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 61.7 61.4;" xml:space="preserve">
                    <style type="text/css">
                        .st0{fill:#fff;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
                    </style>
                    <rect x="20.7" y="5.2" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 19.7538 -17.2354)" class="st0 r1" width="20" height="20"/>
                    <rect x="36.1" y="20.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 35.1571 -23.6156)" class="st0 r2" width="20" height="20"/>
                    <rect x="20.7" y="36" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 41.5374 -8.2123)" class="st0 r3" width="20" height="20"/>
                    <rect x="5.3" y="20.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 26.1341 -1.832)" class="st0 r4" width="20" height="20"/>
                    <g>
                    </svg>
                    <span><a href="#">Categories</a></span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                             viewBox="0 0 61.7 61.4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 61.7 61.4;" xml:space="preserve">
                        <style type="text/css">
                            .st0{fill:#fff;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
                        </style>
                        <rect x="20.7" y="5.2" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 19.7538 -17.2354)" class="st0 r1" width="20" height="20"/>
                        <rect x="36.1" y="20.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 35.1571 -23.6156)" class="st0 r2" width="20" height="20"/>
                        <rect x="20.7" y="36" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 41.5374 -8.2123)" class="st0 r3" width="20" height="20"/>
                        <rect x="5.3" y="20.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 26.1341 -1.832)" class="st0 r4" width="20" height="20"/>
                        <g>
                        </svg>
                        <a href="#">Top Blogs</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                             viewBox="0 0 61.7 61.4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 61.7 61.4;" xml:space="preserve">
                        <style type="text/css">
                            .st0{fill:#fff;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
                        </style>
                        <rect x="20.7" y="5.2" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 19.7538 -17.2354)" class="st0 r1" width="20" height="20"/>
                        <rect x="36.1" y="20.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 35.1571 -23.6156)" class="st0 r2" width="20" height="20"/>
                        <rect x="20.7" y="36" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 41.5374 -8.2123)" class="st0 r3" width="20" height="20"/>
                        <rect x="5.3" y="20.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 26.1341 -1.832)" class="st0 r4" width="20" height="20"/>
                        <g>
                        </svg>
                        <a href="#">Gilded</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                             viewBox="0 0 61.7 61.4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 61.7 61.4;" xml:space="preserve">
                        <style type="text/css">
                            .st0{fill:#fff;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
                        </style>
                        <rect x="20.7" y="5.2" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 19.7538 -17.2354)" class="st0 r1" width="20" height="20"/>
                        <rect x="36.1" y="20.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 35.1571 -23.6156)" class="st0 r2" width="20" height="20"/>
                        <rect x="20.7" y="36" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 41.5374 -8.2123)" class="st0 r3" width="20" height="20"/>
                        <rect x="5.3" y="20.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 26.1341 -1.832)" class="st0 r4" width="20" height="20"/>
                        <g>
                        </svg>
                        <a href="#">Controversial</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: i am not able to si your li's in the code pen. Are the the nav links?

Comment: We'll need the CSS but this sounds like a specificty/selector issue.

Comment: ...also **shortest code** not the full page would be appreciated/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i can come up with with you explanation.

I add a listener to the `hover` event and the `mouseLeave` event.

With this you can target each li

```js
$("li a").each(function(){
  $(this).hover(function(){
    $(this).css('color','red');
  })
  
  $(this).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css('color','white');
  })
})

$(".hamburger").on("click", function(){
 $(".hamburger").toggleClass("is-active");
 if($(".hamburger").hasClass("is-active")){
  $("#main").css("right", "320px");
 } else {
  $("#main").css("right", "20px");
 }
 $(".side-nav").toggleClass("hidden");
 $("body").toggleClass("menu-active");
});
```

```css
html,body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 10000px;
  background-color: pink;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button:focus {outline:0;}

a{
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover, a:active, a:visited, a:focus{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

svg{
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  left: -12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  float: left;
}

.menu-active{
  padding-right: 300px;
}

.side-nav{
  position: fixed;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
}

.open-menu-side{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}

.side-nav-ul{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 40px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

hr{
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.blogs-ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}

.blog{
  height: 150px;
}

.block{
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: #fff;
}

header{
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.hidden{
  position: absolute;
  right: -300px;
}

#main{
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.hamburger {
  padding: 15px 15px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-property: opacity, filter;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-transform: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible; }
  .hamburger:hover {
    opacity: 0.7; }

.hamburger-box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; }

.hamburger-inner {
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px; }
  .hamburger-inner, .hamburger-inner::before, .hamburger-inner::after {
    width: 40px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 0.15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease; }
  .hamburger-inner::before, .hamburger-inner::after {
    content: "";
    display: block; }
  .hamburger-inner::before {
    top: -10px; }
  .hamburger-inner::after {
    bottom: -10px; }


.hamburger--squeeze .hamburger-inner {
  transition-duration: 0.075s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19); }
  .hamburger--squeeze .hamburger-inner::before {
    transition: top 0.075s 0.12s ease, opacity 0.075s ease; }
  .hamburger--squeeze .hamburger-inner::after {
    transition: bottom 0.075s 0.12s ease, transform 0.075s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19); }

.hamburger--squeeze.is-active .hamburger-inner {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition-delay: 0.12s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1); }
  .hamburger--squeeze.is-active .hamburger-inner::before {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: top 0.075s ease, opacity 0.075s 0.12s ease; }
  .hamburger--squeeze.is-active .hamburger-inner::after {
    bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transition: bottom 0.075s ease, transform 0.075s 0.12s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1); }
```

```html
<body>
 <nav class="side-nav hidden">
  <ul class="side-nav-ul">
   <a href="#">

    <li class="block">Home</li>
   </a>
   <hr>
   <li class="blog">
    <a href="#">Blogs</a>
    <ul class="blogs-ul">
     <li class="one">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
        viewBox="0 0 61.7 61.4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 61.7 61.4;" xml:space="preserve">
      <style type="text/css">
       .st0{fill:#fff;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
      </style>
      <rect x="20.7" y="5.2" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 19.7538 -17.2354)" class="st0 r1" width="20" height="20"/>
      <rect x="36.1" y="20.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 35.1571 -23.6156)" class="st0 r2" width="20" height="20"/>
      <rect x="20.7" y="36" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 41.5374 -8.2123)" class="st0 r3" width="20" height="20"/>
      <rect x="5.3" y="20.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 26.1341 -1.832)" class="st0 r4" width="20" height="20"/>
   
      </svg>
      <span><a href="#">Categories</a></span>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div>
       <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 61.7 61.4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 61.7 61.4;" xml:space="preserve">
       <style type="text/css">
        .st0{fill:#fff;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
       </style>
       <rect x="20.7" y="5.2" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 19.7538 -17.2354)" class="st0 r1" width="20" height="20"/>
       <rect x="36.1" y="20.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 35.1571 -23.6156)" class="st0 r2" width="20" height="20"/>
       <rect x="20.7" y="36" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 41.5374 -8.2123)" class="st0 r3" width="20" height="20"/>
       <rect x="5.3" y="20.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 26.1341 -1.832)" class="st0 r4" width="20" height="20"/>
    
       </svg>
       <a href="#">Top Blogs</a>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div>
       <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 61.7 61.4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 61.7 61.4;" xml:space="preserve">
       <style type="text/css">
        .st0{fill:#fff;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
       </style>
       <rect x="20.7" y="5.2" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 19.7538 -17.2354)" class="st0 r1" width="20" height="20"/>
       <rect x="36.1" y="20.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 35.1571 -23.6156)" class="st0 r2" width="20" height="20"/>
       <rect x="20.7" y="36" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 41.5374 -8.2123)" class="st0 r3" width="20" height="20"/>
       <rect x="5.3" y="20.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 26.1341 -1.832)" class="st0 r4" width="20" height="20"/>
 
       </svg>
       <a href="#">Gilded</a>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div>
       <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 61.7 61.4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 61.7 61.4;" xml:space="preserve">
       <style type="text/css">
        .st0{fill:#fff;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
       </style>
       <rect x="20.7" y="5.2" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 19.7538 -17.2354)" class="st0 r1" width="20" height="20"/>
       <rect x="36.1" y="20.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 35.1571 -23.6156)" class="st0 r2" width="20" height="20"/>
       <rect x="20.7" y="36" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 41.5374 -8.2123)" class="st0 r3" width="20" height="20"/>
       <rect x="5.3" y="20.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 26.1341 -1.832)" class="st0 r4" width="20" height="20"/>
      
       </svg>
       <a href="#">Controversial</a>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <hr>
   <a href="#"><li class="block">Following</li></a>
   <hr>
   <a href="#"><li class="block">Profile</li></a> 
   <hr>
   <a href="#"><li class="block">Settings</li></a>
   <hr>
   <a href="#"><li class="block">Logout</li></a>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <header id="pushed">
  <nav>
   <div class="open-menu" id="main">
    <button class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze" type="button">
      <span class="hamburger-box">
        <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
      </span>
    </button>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </header>
 <section></section>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Love when i get a downvote. Vote i love when i can know why so i can improve.